# java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, cascade, illegalstateexception, persist

I have two 2 classes in relation many to many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipies")
public class Recipie implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String url;
private String image;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "recipie_ingredients",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "recipie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();






@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients")
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients") 
    private List<Recipie> recipies;
```

I would like to create a new recipie this way:

```
List<Ingredient> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();


String ingredientName = "example";

Ingredient ingredient = ingredientsDao.findIngredientByName(ingredientName);

if (ingredient == null) {
   ingredient = new Ingredient();
   ingredient.setName(ingredientName);

}
ingredientsList.add(ingredient);
.....
recipie.setIngredients(ingredientsList);
recipiesDao.addRecipie(recipie);
```

If ingredient doesn't exist in database, occur errors like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST
```

Is there any way to Ingredient objects created in the table automatically?

I try add CascadeType.PERSIST but It also doesn't work

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
private List<Recipie> recipies;
```

Comment: When working with a ManyToMany, you need to update the collections in both the ingredient and the recipie. So you add the recipie to the ingredient, and you add the ingredient to the recipie. Are you doing that?

Comment: No, my new ingredient does not exist in the database.  JPA should automatically create appropriate record in ingredients table and relation.is the way to do it?

Comment: that reply only means you don't understand what I'm saying. But both Adam and Steve explain it better in their answers.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, for a bidirectional relationship, both sides need to be updated, so:

```
recipe.getIngredients().add(ingredient);
ingredient.getRecipes().add(recipe);
```

Then, you can set the cascade to `PERSIST` on the side of the relationship which you are passing to `save()`. So if you are saving the `recipe`, you should mark the `Recipe.ingredients` with

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

*(Side note, it's spelled "recipe", not "recip**i**e")*

Comment: cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST this duplicate records in database. 

I am adding recipies in loop.

Comment: If you're getting duplicate records in the DB, then possibly there's more to your code than you posted. That can happen if the transactions or entity manager are not used correctly or the entity model is incorrect. Can't say without seeing more of your code. When well used, `CascadeType.PERSIST` should never duplicate any records.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Gimby, you need to assign both sides of the relationship.

When dealing with @Many... sided relationships I always initialise the collection (which you've done on one side):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipies")
public class Recipie implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String image;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "recipie_ingredients",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "recipie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients")
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients") 
    private List<Recipie> recipies = new ArrayList<>(); 

    ...
}
```

And then a slight variation in your logic:

```
String ingredientName = "example";

Ingredient ingredient = ingredientsDao.findIngredientByName(ingredientName);

if (ingredient == null) {
   ingredient = new Ingredient();
   ingredient.setName(ingredientName);

}
...

// Don't forget to assign both sides of the relationship
recipe.getIngredients().add(ingredient);
ingredient.getRecipies().add(recipe);
recipiesDao.addRecipe(recipe);
```

This should then cascade persist/update correctly.

The real fun will begin when you try to figure out how to associate a quantity with the ingredient...